# How to call another function's results

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

```
def most_frequency_occ(chars,inputString):
    count = 0
    for ind_char in inputString:
        ind_char = ind_char.lower()
        if chars == ind_char:
             count += 1
    return count

def general(inputString):
    maxOccurences = 0
    for chars in inputString:
        most_frequency_occ(chars, inputString)
```

This is my current code. I'm trying to find the most frequent occurring letter in `general`. I created another function called `most_frequency_occ` that finds a specific character in the string that occurs the most often, but how do I generalize it into finding the frequent letter in a string without specifying a specific character and only using loops, without any build in string functions either.

For example:

```
print(general('aqweasdaza'))
```

should print `4` as `"a"` occurs the most frequently, occurring 4 times.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you give us an input and output example, please? I think that your problem doesn't clear enough.

Comment: What is your "main"? Are you execute `general` with your whole text as `inputString`?

Comment: Anyway, I think that this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-frequency-of-each-character-in-string/) would be helpful for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your task, I think that using a dictionary will be more comfortable for you.

```
 # initializing string  
 str = "Hello world"

 # initializing dict of freq
 freq = {} 

     for i in str: 
         if i in freq: 
              freq[i] += 1
         else: 
              freq[i] = 1

 # Now, you have the count of every char in this string.
 # If you want to extract the max, this step will do it for you:

 max_freq_chr = max(stats.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you find the most common letter in a string.

One easy to understand and cross-language way of doing this would be:

1. initialize an array of 26 integers set to 0.
2. go over each letter one by one of your string, if the first letter is an B (B=2), you can increment the second value of the array
3. Find the largest value in your array, return the corresponding letter.

Since you are using python, you could use dictionaries since it would be less work to implement.

*A word of caution*, it sounds like you are doing a school assignment. If your school has a plagiarism checker that checks the internet, you might be caught for academic dishonesty if you copy paste code from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have suggested alternative ways of counting the letters in a string, some of which may be better than what you've come up with on your own. But I think it may be worth answering your question about how to call your `most_frequency_occ` function from your `general` function even if the algorithm isn't great, since you'll need to understand how functions work in other contexts.

The thing to understand about function calls is that the call expression will be evaluated to the value returned by the function. In this case, that's the count. Often you may want to assign the return value to a variable so you can reference it multiple times. Here's what that might look like:

```
count = most_frequency_occ(chars, inputString)
```

Now you can do a comparsion between the count and the previously best count to see if you've just checked the most common letter so far:

```
maxOccurences = 0
for chars in inputString:
    count = most_frequency_occ(chars, inputString)
    if count > maxOccurences:  # check if chars is more common than the previous best
        maxOccurences = count
return maxOccurences
```

One final note: Some of your variable and function names are a bit misleading. That often happens when you're changing your code around from one design to another, but not changing the variable names at the same time. You may want to occasionally reread your code and double check to make sure that the variable names still match what you're doing with them. If not, you should "refactor" your code by renaming the variables to better match their actual uses.

To be specific, your `most_frequency_occ` function isn't actually finding the most frequent character itself, it's only doing a small step in that process, counting how often a single character occurs. So I'd call it `count_char` or something similar. The `general` function might be named something more descriptive like `find_most_frequent_character`.

And the variable `chars` (which exists in both functions) is also misleading since it represents a single character, but the name `chars` implies something plural (like a list or a string that contains several characters). Renaming it to `char` might be better, as that seems more like a singular name.